# Appending / concatenating one string to elements of a list of strings (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, string, list, append, concatenation

Perhaps this has been answered, but I sincerely could not find it.

I wish to have a specific output in the form of:

```
("A_1", "A_2", ..., "A_100")
```

I tried:

```
a = "A_"
nums_1_100 = str(list(range(1,101)))
for i in range (1,101):
    x = a
    x += nums_1_100
```

And this returns:

```
'A_[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 100]'
```

Comment: Using map `print(list(map(lambda x: 'A_%d' % x, range(1, 101))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes no sense as you overwrite `x` each iteration, which in result kills what your code produced in previous one. You want rather to use simple list comprehension instead:

```
result = [ 'A_%d' % i for i in range(1,101)]
```

which would then produce list with elements like `A_1`, `A_2` ...

Comment: Thanks :) I suppose I could've known it didn't make sense, and thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to make that list of strings like:

```
x = ['A_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 101)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the functional approach. This will work with a list of any type, so if you decided to switch from ints at the end to strings/characters, all that would need to change would be the contents of `listToAppend`.

```
listToAppend = list(range(1, 101))
output = list(map(lambda x: "A_" + str(x), listToAppend))
```

Comment: I am afraid that this is the type of approach we call "over-engeneering". As result, you will end up with the code that is universal for no real benefits, hard to understand and complicated for every single simple task.